# SQL for getting a queue of users - For Game

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Greetings!

I am currently building a match making logic for an online chess game.

However, I am having a lot of troubles figuring out how to come up with a logic to get a pool of users that would be competed to one another.

So basically, I have my database tables designed like these:

```
Users
-------
ID   |   Username   |   Gender

1    |   GKasparov  |   Male
2    |   MCarlsen   |   Male
3    |   VKramnik   |   Male
4    |   JPolgar    |   Female
5    |   HYifan     |   Female
6    |   KHumpy     |   Female
......
```

And another table for storing their elorating

```
ELO
------

ID   |   Rating

1    |   2000
2    |   1990
3    |   1800
4    |   1990
5    |   1980
6    |   1700
.......
```

I need to come up with a way to gather up to 10 pairs of users for each query that would be matched to one another.

So in my search result, I need 10 groups of two users for a total of twenty users.

The result I am thinking of is going to be like:

```
Group 1: #1, #41 (Males Match)
Group 2: #2, #55 (Males Match)
Group 3: #3, #22 (Males Match)
Group 4: #4, #55 (Females Match)
Group 5: #5, #23 (Females Match)
.......
Group 10: #6, #13 (Females Match)
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Also, only Males can be matched up against Males and perhaps in the future, their elorating would be considered.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am also using PHP as my application server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try anything already?

Comment: actually the 1st question here is what method are you using to build the match up? Round Robin? or Double Round Robin? or something like that. And I think you can do this on `php` not in MySQL.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I wasn't aware that chess matches and tournaments are still gender segregated:

https://plus.google.com/110558272289309146867/posts/H4rHtzg7Bn3

Comment: thanks for the replies, 
@ fabio I have tried some queries but have been failing horribly and are not worth posting. 
@ ulfric right now it doesn't really matter but in the future they want round robin format
@ jim actually the participants requested it to be gender segregated.

Comment: There are a couple of open source systems which implement chess pairing algorithms (Swiss pairings).  I don't know if studying these would taint your project or whether you could do even derive your code directly from them (if yours is to be GPL, for example, or if it's to be available only as a service for GPL 2.x or earlier).

Here they are: http://www.twinfeats.com/tf/twinfeats/Java/pairings/index.tfs and

http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/details/chess_league.html and http://soss.sourceforge.net/  .. I just used the Google search "chess pairing source code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I would use a subselect to get every combination of users, order by the first user id with the 2nd user id being in a random order. Then add a counter variable and only bring back the first one for each first user id.

Crudely done (and not tested), but something like this:-

```
SELECT CONCAT("GROUP ", @Group := @Group + 1), CONCAT("#", Player1), CONCAT("#", Player2), MatchType
FROM (
SELECT a.ID AS Player1, b.ID AS Player2, CONCAT("(", a.Gender, " Match)") AS MatchType, (CASE WHEN @aUser = a.ID THEN @Cnt = @Cnt + 1 ELSE @Cnt END) AS rownum, @aUser := a.ID
FROM users a
INNER JOIN users b
ON a.Gender = b.Gender
AND a.ID != b.ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT @Cnt := 0, @aUser := NULL) c
ORDER BY a.ID, RAND()) Sub1
INNER JOIN (SELECT @Group := 0) c
WHERE Sub1.rownum = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Issue with this (at the moment) is that #1 could play #2, but that could also be returned as #2 playing #1. It will need some effort to remove this issue.

EDIT - easy way to fix the duplicates. Change the AND in the JOIN from **AND a.ID != b.ID** to **AND a.ID < b.ID**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 function scheduler($players){

        if (count($players)%2 != 0){

            array_push($players,"bye");

        }

        $away = array_splice($players,(count($players)/2));

        $home = $players;

        for ($i=0; $i < count($home)+count($away)-1; $i++){

            for ($j=0; $j<count($home); $j++){

                $round[$i][$j]["Home"]=$home[$j];

                $round[$i][$j]["Away"]=$away[$j];

            }

            if(count($home)+count($away)-1 > 2){

                array_unshift($away,array_shift(array_splice($home,1,1)));

                array_push($home,array_pop($away));

            }

        }

        return $round;

    }

    ?>
```

to display the match up:

```
foreach($schedule AS $round => $games){

    echo "Group: ".($round+1)."<BR>";

    foreach($games AS $play){

        echo $play["Home"]." - ".$play["Away"]."<BR>";

    }

    echo "<BR>";

}

?>
```

get the array of teams using mysql query for team names. the `$round` contains the 'away' and 'home' match ups.

Comment: Assuming that match up algorithm is in round robin and not gender dependent.